# How to delete Json particular element in C#?

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

```
 public class students
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string fName { get; set; }
        public string mName { get; set; }
        public string lName { get; set; }
        public string Dept { get; set; }
        public string Degree { get; set; }
        public _Semister[] ComplitedSemister { get; set; }
       
        public string SemesterCode { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        
    }
    
    public class _Semister
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Instructor { get; set; }
        public int Credit { get; set; }
    }
```

This is My student class

```
[
  {
    "ID": 101,
    "fName": "Kamal",
    "mName": "Faheem",
    "lName": "Khabib",
    "Dept": "CSE",
    "Degree": "BSC",
    "ComplitedSemister": [
      {
        "Id": 2001,
        "Name": "OOP",
        "Instructor": "Jamal",
        "Credit": 2354
      }
    ],
    "SemesterCode": "Summer",
    "Year": "2014"
  },
  {
    "ID": 454,
    "fName": "fdgfdg",
    "mName": "sgdfsd",
    "lName": "sdfgg",
    "Dept": "fdgsdf",
    "Degree": "sfdgdf",
    "ComplitedSemister": [
      {
        "Id": 324,
        "Name": "cgbf",
        "Instructor": "dgfd",
        "Credit": 54
      }
    ],
    "SemesterCode": "Ummer",
    "Year": "3423"
  }

]
```

This is my Json File. I want to delete all element for a particular ID. For example, for ID = 101 I want delete whole data for this ID. SO the next ID = 454 become the first student in json file. But I can't Delete . SO how can I delete ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by 2 ways ( I am using Newtonsoft.Json. You can install it by Nuget)

1. Parse Json to a JArray. Remove item from array. Serialize  the JArray.

```
//your json
var json="[{\"ID\":101,\"fName\":\"Kamal\",\"mName\":\"Faheem\",\"lName\":\"Khabib\",\"Dept\":\"CSE\",\"Degree\":\"BSC\",\"ComplitedSemister\":[{\"Id\":2001,\"Name\":\"OOP\",\"Instructor\":\"Jamal\",\"Credit\":2354}],\"SemesterCode\":\"Summer\",\"Year\":\"2014\"},{\"ID\":454,\"fName\":\"fdgfdg\",\"mName\":\"sgdfsd\",\"lName\":\"sdfgg\",\"Dept\":\"fdgsdf\",\"Degree\":\"sfdgdf\",\"ComplitedSemister\":[{\"Id\":324,\"Name\":\"cgbf\",\"Instructor\":\"dgfd\",\"Credit\":54}],\"SemesterCode\":\"Ummer\",\"Year\":\"3423\"}]";

var jArray=JArray.Parse(json);

var itemToRemove = (JToken) jArray.Where(a => (int) a["ID"]==101).First();  
jArray.Remove(itemToRemove);

json=jArray.ToString();
```

2. Deserialize  JSON to strongly-typed list of items. Remove item from list. Serialize the list.

```
var json= ...your json..;

var jDeserialized= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<students>>(json);
var removeItem=jDeserialized.Where(d =>d.Id==101 ).First();
jDeserialized.Remove(removeItem);
json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject (jDeserialized, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

result json

```
[
  {
    "ID": 454,
    "fName": "fdgfdg",
    "mName": "sgdfsd",
    "lName": "sdfgg",
    "Dept": "fdgsdf",
    "Degree": "sfdgdf",
    "ComplitedSemister": [
      {
        "Id": 324,
        "Name": "cgbf",
        "Instructor": "dgfd",
        "Credit": 54
      }
    ],
    "SemesterCode": "Ummer",
    "Year": 3423
  }
]
```

Comment: var jArray=JArray.Parse(json);  What is json in this line. Where I declare this ..can u please explane. I am beginner.

Comment: @FarhatSnigdho Json is your json text that you posted in your question. I posted  result   json too.